# Data filtering from large CSV

Tags: python, csv, filter

I have a large data file and I'm only interested in rows with specific x values of `4.125` as shown below. Now because the value of `4.125` relates to the stop position of the ion, the corresponding start position is also of interest to me and I want to keep this information in the array.

How do I write a program which effectively finds the x stop position of `4.125` and retains the ion start position?

It is a `120982 * 9` array and in the example shown below I would be interested in keeping the information of ion # `3849096`.

```
"Ion N","Mass","Charge","X","Y","Z","Azm","Elv","KE" 
3849094,0.00054858,-1,66.5216,-51,-3.8,-180,88.7,18160
3849094,0.00054858,-1,27.3925,30.3532,-4.07076,-177.1,41.5494,17697.2 
3849095,0.00054858,-1,66.5216,-51,-3.7,-180,88.7,18160
3849095,0.00054858,-1,26.6277,31.0039,-3.91402,-177.096,40.8293,17699.4
3849096,0.00054858,-1,66.5216,-51,-3.6,-180,88.7,18160
3849096,0.00054858,-1,4.125,44.9887,-2.47517,-176.363,25.715,17711.1
```

This is the code I have developed so far but does not work:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

opts = pd.read_csv('Ambre_2.dat',sep = ',', low_memory = False)
df = pd.DataFrame(opts)

X = df.iloc[:,3]
IonN = df.iloc[:,0]
tol = 1e-6
Fltr = 4.125

filterreddata = df[abs(df['X'] - Fltr) < tol]
filteredions = df[np.in1d(df['Ion N'], filterreddata['Ion N'])]
filteredions[2:2:end, :] = []
f = open('ions.csv', 'w')
f.write(tabulate(filteredions))
f.close()
```

The ions.csv file should look like this:

```
"Ion N","Mass","Charge","X","Y","Z","Azm","Elv","KE" 
348450  0.00054858  -1  50.2216 -41 0.9 0   88.1    9200
348451  0.00054858  -1  50.3216 -41 0.9 0   88.1    9200 
348511  0.00054858  -1  50.2216 -41 1   0   88.1    9200
348512  0.00054858  -1  50.3216 -41 1   0   88.1    9200
```

Comment: Seems like you have a typo here: `df(np.in1d(df.IonN, filterreddata.IonN), :]`. In addition, can you define clearly `retains the ion start position`? I don't understand what you're looking for with this.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show what your `ions.csv` file should look like for that data?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have added a sample of the data output file I desire to the question. What I mean by retain ion data from start position is that in the raw data file I get recordings of the start and stop positions for each ion. Now for me to filter out the ions that I require, I need to know their stop positions.

Comment: Once the filter has identified the ions with the stop position of 4.125, I then use the ion number to extract from the raw data file ions which match these ion numbers. As you can see in the question above the desired csv file contains only one instance of each ion rather than two (as they appear in the raw data). I hope I have explained this well. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: @jpp yes there is a typo. I have edited the question with the correction.